Vertical alignment problems with marginnote and titlesec
I'm with a document that has margin notes in the section titles. I have programmed a command that works if I don't load titlesec package. Here is a minimal example:

\documentclass[a4,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{calc}

% \usepackage{titlesec} % No titlesec crap, works

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\newcommand{\margen}[2][0pt]{%
  \marginnote{%
    \normalfont\footnotesize
    \checkoddpage    
    \ifoddpage {\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright{\normalfont\footnotesize#2\normalfont}}}
    \else      {\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedleft{\normalfont\footnotesize#2\normalfont}}}
    \fi
  }[#1]
}


\newlength\altura
\setlength{\altura}{\heightof{{\Large C}}}
%\setlength{\altura}{\heightof{{C}}}
%\setlength{\altura}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section[Uno]{One\marginnote{Test text}}

\blindtext[1]

\section[Dos]{Two \margen{Another secion note}}
\blindtext[1]

\section[Tres]{Three\margen{\blindtext}}%

\blindtext[2]

\section[Four]%
%{Four \margen[-\altura]{Fourth note \\and a little more text}} %  One of the tests modifying the height.
% With the configuration of this file, it does not work.
{Four \margen{Fourth note \\and a little more text}}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

The problem is that when I activate titlesec, an extra vertical space appears, I don't know where it comes from. I've been testing with marginnote's loading parameters, but it means having to insert vertical elements for the correct alignment. Another solution I was considering, is to force a vertical movement, but I can't find a convenient way to know the size of the extra space included in titlesec.
I would be happy to receive any solution, suggestion or hint to solve this.
Best regards.
Edit:
This is the correct alignment form:

And this is the wrong way, when titlesec is loaded:


Shouldn't it be \iffoddpage in which case the code does not compile. What exactly is that off page suppose to do? There are way too many } in that macro

@daleif, You' re right, there was a mistake when copying the code. I've added some screenshots showing the correct and the incorrect alignment

There is no a4 option. It's a4paper.

With titlesec you need to raise by the \baselineskip.
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{titlesec} % No titlesec crap, works

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\margen}[2][0pt]{%
  \marginnote{%
    \normalfont\footnotesize
    \checkoddpage    
    \parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{%
      \ifoddpage\raggedright\else\raggedleft\fi#2%
    }%
  }[\dimeval{#1-\baselineskip}]
}

\begin{document}

\section[Uno]{\margen{Test text}One}

\lipsum[1]

\section[Dos]{\margen{Another secion note}Two}
\lipsum[1]

\section[Tres]{Three\margen{\lipsum[3][1-2]}}%

\lipsum[2-3]

\section[Four]%
{Four \margen{Fourth note \\and a little more text}}
With the configuration of this file, it does not work.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

I simplified the code. Of course, the margin notes go in the outer margin.


